# Put two Cron jobs into crontab using wget

Tags: cron, wget, repository

I am trying to put these two Cron Jobs:

```
0 3 * * * ! sudo -u asterisk /var/lib/asterisk/bin/module_admin  --repos extended,standard,unsupported upgradeall

30 3 * * * ! sudo -u asterisk /var/lib/asterisk/bin/module_admin reload
```

into a repository so that i can run a

```
wget www.website.com cronjob.(zip or text)
```

How would I save those so that I can inject them into crontab and how?

*sorry if this is very simple, but I am very new and other web resources haven't been any help*

Comment: why can't you just copy and paste them in via crontab -e

Comment: @coteyr I did that on my test server but there are 50+ servers and virtual machines that i need to install this on and more when we set them up. Very small company and I'm only a teenager, sorry if that was frustrating :/

Comment: I would suggest a push setup instead. Use SCP or rsync to push the files to all your hosts. It would be easier to extend when adding new servers to the group. VM's are even better, set up one base image, then one master image based off the base, then one it's setup and tested just copy it 50 times.

Comment: It looks fairly simple, I will look into implementing that. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a HUGE security risk, but

```
wget www.website.com cronjob.txt
crontab -u username cronjob.txt
```

But your crontab looks wrong. Why do you need to sudo, cron jobs run as the user they are installed for. So you would be better to just put the lines in asterisk's crontab.

```
sudo crontab -u asterisk
```

then add

```
0 3 * * *   /var/lib/asterisk/bin/module_admin  --repos extended,standard,unsupported upgradeall

30 3 * * *  /var/lib/asterisk/bin/module_admin reload
```

Comment: You're right about the cron job, that is a fault on my part. I appreciate the help. I am grabbing the text file off of my own personal site so no security risk, and with my firewall only my IP can access it. Otherwise this would be horrible and I agree. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -O - www.website.com/cronjob.gz|zcat|sudo tee -a /etc/crontab
```

or

```
crontab -l | cat - <(wget -O - www.website.com/cronjob.gz|zcat)| crontab -
```

The disadvantage of these commands is that they do not check to verify that the commands do not exist. You are better off using crontab.d or cron.d directories if they exist and creating a file in them with the service you are working with. the other option would be a fancier script like

```
grep '^### Next three lines added by script 456' /etc/crontab && exit
sudo tee -a /etc/crontab <<< EOF
0 3 * * * ! sudo -u asterisk /var/lib/asterisk/bin/module_admin  --repos extended,standard,unsupported upgradeall
30 3 * * * ! sudo -u asterisk /var/lib/asterisk/bin/module_admin reload
EOF
```

and invoke it as

```
wget -O - www.website.com/script.gz|zcat|bash
```

or

```
bash <(wget -O - www.website.com/script.gz|zcat)
```

P.S. There are some fun issues running sudo from cron, I don't think you want to do that, but that is a difrent question.

Comment: This would work fine. I just want to stress again how horrid a security risk it is to run random text file downloaded from a website. It would work though.

Comment: If it is your file, from your website the only issue is being manipulated midstream either accidentally (which compression will catch with a checksum) or deliberately (which is why you should use https). If it is not your file, check it.